# RegEx to prepare csv file for Oracle DB: How to remove double-quotes within each string

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a csv file that I need to load into an Oracle DB.

I am stuck on the preparation task and am looking for a RegEx to accomplish the following task:

Starting from this example:

```
"FC2010", "FC020212", "Park "red" in front </br> of the "house"", "my 2nd "birthday" was in 2013"
```

I need to define a RegEx the remove double-quote (") that are within the field value.

Therefore, the expected output should be:

```
"FC2010", "FC020212", "Park red in front </br> of the house", "my 2nd birthday was in 2013"
```

As you can see, in the result the double-quotes are **exclusively** used to delimit fields and they have been remove from within the string value.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this pattern:**

```
(\"[\w\d]+\"\,\s)|(\<\/[a-z]{2}\>)\s([a-z]+)\s|(?-i:\", \"[\w\d]+)|\s[a-z]+\s[a-z]+\s[\w\d]+\"|([\w\d\s]+)|\"([A-Z])
```

You can test it [online](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This `(?<!,\s\s)(?<!,\s)(?<!^)"(?!\s*,|\s*$)` **may** work for you (see disclaimer below)

https://regex101.com/r/eHGPxX/1/

Regular expressions are not intelligent and cannot now if, for example, at this string `"hi"there"!"` the first `"` closes on `hi` or at the end. We can try to add some rules in order to get a better match. For example, on your test string the real `"` seem to be separated by `,` So one approach could be to just ignore the `"` that have `,` near.

But even then things like this will fail: `"   hi "peter" , "how are you?"  "`

However if strings like that cannot happen inside your data, the regexp should work for you.